# mySQL previous/next query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out a way to have a **previous** and **next** button to display more data for a given query-sorta like a pagination would do.

The query is this:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
        FROM wp_posts p
            LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x ON x.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = x.term_id
            LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.id = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND pm.meta_key = 'xTraData'
        AND p.post_type = 'post'
        AND t.slug = 'press-coverage'
        ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT 0,6;";
```

How can i get the **previous id** and **next id** to use for the next/previous buttons for refreshing the query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get them using $_GET variables, which can be sent from URL. Process them to raise you limits.

A mysql limit defines how much rows to fetch and from where to fetch.

So, `0, 6` in your query say start from `0` (first) and select `6` rows.

```
$p_num = isset($_GET['pagenumber']) && (int)$_GET['pagenumber'] > 0 ? $_GET['pagenumber'] : 0;
$p_size = 6;

$query = "SELECT * 
        FROM wp_posts p
            LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x ON x.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = x.term_id
            LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.id = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND pm.meta_key = 'xTraData'
        AND p.post_type = 'post'
        AND t.slug = 'press-coverage'
        ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT ".(($p_num-1) * $p_size).",".$p_size.";";
```

Now, send a request like: `yourpage.php?pagenumber=2` and it will query the second page where a page will hold about 6 items.

Comment: so pagenumber=0 would product **0,6** but pagenumber=1 would produce **10,6**.. shouldnt that be **5,6**?

Comment: so if p_num is **0** then its **-6** (0-1 * 6)?

Comment: @StealthRT, That is basic airthmetic. This is not a write a code for me community. Anyways check the update.

Comment: i was saying that **$p_num-1** needs to be **$p_num** without the **-1**.

Comment: @StealthRT, Actually, when you query for second page (2), the limit should start from 5, not 11, so `-1` is necessary. Try out my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in variables for the LIMIT bounds. In this instance **previous id** would be `null` and **next id** could be 7. If you always want **X** records at a time you could do `LIMIT $next_ID, ($next_ID + $X)` and modify your previous and next variables accordingly.